# PIXI.JS Newbie, looking for advice and troubleshoot of a textureCache, loader issue

Tags: javascript, textures, sprite, loader, pixi.js

ive ventured into the world of PIXI and JS, new programming language for me, liking the way it is right now but i have an issue.

I am a bit confused with the TextureCache and the loader. If you look at part of my code i try to add 3 different images to the screen. Ive been following the 'Get Started section' of the pixi website. I wanted to add their cat image, which i have, the tileset image (all of it)* and then a tile of the tileset image.

The issue is, i create 3 new sprite instances and the tileset image shows the area ive set for the tile(rocket) when i want it to show the whole tileset. Ive loaded in the tileset iin the cahce and the loader.

Why does tile show the cropped image and not the whole image?
Am i using the cache correctly to just store images?
Am i using the resources method properly to locate the image FROM the cache or the loader?
Is there any point of the cache?

my thoughts** 
when you use the rectangle method, it destroys the original image and the cropped version is now tileset1 (the name of my image)?

```js
<html>
<body>

<script src="pixi.js"></script>

<script>
//Aliases
let Application = PIXI.Application,
    loader = PIXI.loader,
    resources = PIXI.loader.resources,
    Sprite = PIXI.Sprite,
 Rectangle = PIXI.Rectangle,
 TextureCache = PIXI.utils.TextureCache;
 

let app = new PIXI.Application({ 
    width: 1000, 
    height: 600,                       
    antialias: true, 
    transparent: false, 
    resolution: 1
  }
);

//Add the canvas that Pixi automatically created for you to the HTML document
document.body.appendChild(app.view);
TextureCache["tileset1.png","images/3.png"];
//load an image and run the `setup` function when it's done
loader.add(["images/3.png","tileset1.png"]).load(setup);

//This `setup` function will run when the image has loaded
function setup() {
 let texture = TextureCache["tileset1.png"];
 let rectangle = new Rectangle(96,64,32,32);
 texture.frame = rectangle;
 

  //Create the cat sprite, use a texture from the loader
  let card = new Sprite(resources["images/3.png"].texture);
  let tile = new Sprite(resources["tileset1.png"].texture);
  let rocket = new Sprite(texture);
  
  card.scale.set(0.06,0.06);
  
  tile.x=400;
  tile.y=400;
  
  rocket.x=100;
  rocket.y=100;
  
  //Add the cat to the stage
  app.stage.addChild(card);
  app.stage.addChild(tile);
  app.stage.addChild(rocket);
  
  app.renderer.render(app.stage);
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/5.2.4/pixi.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Is there any point of the cache?` - this question seems to be most important from your questions :)

Searching around about "pixi.js" and "TextureCache" gives following answers for example:

- https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/issues/4053

  > MySecret commented on May 23, 2017:
  >
  > the docs has no specs about PIXI.utils.TextureCache
  >
  > ...
  >
  > englercj commented on May 26, 2017
  >
  > This is intentional, it is not meant as a public-facing API. It is an internal cache used by some texture creation methods.
- https://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/17788-loader-and-texturecache-tutorial-anywhere/

  > xerver - Pixi.js Moderator:
  >
  > Here is the loader: https://github.com/englercj/resource-loader
  >
  > The code is really well documented, and there are examples on the readme. The pixi examples also use the loader a few times: http://pixijs.github.io/examples/
  >
  > **The TextureCache is an internal mechanism, there is rarely any reason you should even know it exists.**
- https://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/25575-pixiloaderresources-or-texturecache/

  > xerver - Pixi.js Moderator:
  >
  > Dont do this:
  >
  > `let e = PIXI.utils.TextureCache[player.img];`
  >
  > Instead use the resources the loader loaded for you:
  >
  > `let e = PIXI.loader.resources[player.img].texture;`
  >
  > ...

**TLDR**: Usually TextureCache shouldnt be used directly :)

See also:

- this explanation: https://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/9255-pixijs-caching/?tab=comments#comment-55233
- http://pixijs.download/release/docs/PIXI.BaseTexture.html#.addToCache

  - ^ example of usage: https://jsfiddle.net/themoonrat/br35x20j/